# Когда запускаю iOS симулятор пропадает wi-fi соединение

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

запускаю ios симулятор в xcode, вайфай соединение начинает плохо работать и долго грузить,а  когда закрываю симулятор, то вайфай начинает работать хорошо и грузит все быстро
Macbook Air m1 2020  у меня. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это связано с тем, что симулятор при запуске как минимум часто, а как максимум каждый раз (давно не отслеживал) начинает грузить обновления объемом по несколько сотен мегабайт, и может тем самым снижать скорость загрузки, тем более если она и так невысока. Я столкнулся с подобным поведением и изложил его в данном [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677748/get-info-about-ios-simulator-traffic). Решением для меня стала блокировка соединения симулятора для скачки обновлений с помощью программы Little Snitch (она оказалась наиболее удобной, но возможно есть и другие варианты)